# Why is sshd getting restarted when yum cron starts?

Tags: ssh, yum, upgrade

I have a new server build (Centos 6.6), and have yum-cron installed and running in cron.daily.

In looking through my `messages` and `secure` logs, it appears that right after yum starts updating and installing, sshd is getting restarted. I have googled and checked my server setup and other logs, but to no avail.

Here are the two log excerpts in question:

**messages:**

```
Apr 22 04:06:36 members yum[21035]: Updated: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64

Apr 22 04:06:40 members yum[21035]: Updated: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64

Apr 22 04:06:41 members yum[21035]: Updated: glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64

Apr 22 04:06:41 members yum[21035]: Updated: glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64
```

**secure:**

```
Apr 22 04:06:37 members sshd[21952]: Received signal 15; terminating.

Apr 22 04:06:40 members sshd[21096]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.

Apr 22 04:06:40 members sshd[21096]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out **why**. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is anything else running at that time, like logrotate?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Several other things run immediately after yum-cron does: clamav update, logrotate, makewhatis, and mlocate - in that order. They all start within 20 seconds of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glibc upgrades often require restarting running daemons (because the name service switch [NSS] ABI changes, or just to get the daemon to actually used the upgraded version). That's probably what you're seeing.

Comment: Ah - I was unaware of this. Glad to see it is expected behavior.